# preg_match_all alpha+accented, but not numeric

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-negation

I would like to use PHP's preg_match_all to capture substrings which comprise:

- A-Z, a-z, all accented chars;
- space;
- hyphen.

It must not capture strings with anything else in them, including numeric chars.

This example is close but also catches strings containing numeric chars:

```
preg_match_all("/([\w -]+)/u", $abigstring, $matches);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to match just ASCII accented characters or Unicode included?

Comment: @GigaWatt: "all accented letters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a job for Unicode properties:

```
preg_match_all("/([\p{L} -]+)/u", $abigstring, $matches);
```

`\p{L}` matches any character with the Unicode property "Letter".

Comment: Genius.  Thanks for that.  Anyone else searching can look up this earth magic Tim calls Unicode Properties: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

There's a whole side of regex to explore here!

Answer (score 2):

This is also an option :

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ -]+/u", "", "juana 123456 sfdf 423 999 _ -a- dsa & ç%& à à$¨à+", -1);
```

Here is a working example -> https://xrg.es/#17hyhfm

Comment: This replaces also hyphen `-` that is not wanted.

Comment: @M42 You're right! I forgot the hyphen. I edited my answer and everything is good now.

Comment: OK, +1 for alternative to `\pL`. But I think `\pL` is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

For those want to, here is a correction of the code above which doesn't work !

```
preg_match("/^([\p{L} -]+)$/u", $string)
```

Anchors (^ and $) were missing

EDIT : Much better. If hyphens/spaces are only allowed in the middle:

```
/^([\p{L}](?:[\p{L} -]+[\p{L}])?)$/u
```

Comment: Where did you see he wants to capture all the string?